# Python Openpyxl schedule replace timestamp range with string

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have workers that starts and end their workdays different times. I get a *.xlsx from a old schedule
program where i see their schedule. I want to replace their time with a string instead.
For example:
'13:00 - 21:30', '13:30 - 21:30','14:00 - 21:30','15:00 - 21:30' with a single 'name'('a-tur').

my code so far is:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

wb.sheetnames
worksheet = wb["Sheet"]
antal_rader = ws.max_column
antal_kolumn = ws.max_row
for r in range(antal_rader):
    for c in range(antal_kolumn):
        cellValue = str(worksheet[get_column_letter(r+1)+str(c+1)].value)
        if cellValue == 'a':
            worksheet[get_column_letter(r+1)+str(c+1)] = 'a-tur'

    
wb.save('sample.xlsx')
```

Thanks for all the help i can get.

Sincerely
Dan

Comment: and what is wrong with your code?

Comment: i need to set a range in 'cellValue ==  'range value', i dont get it to work

Comment: Why are you checking for "a" if you want to replace times? Using the openpyxl API would make this a lot easier.

Comment: I worked it out. I can understand that 'a' is confusing. 'a' should be a timestamp like in string '13:00 - 21:30'. Im new to python and excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
for r in range(antal_rader):
    for c in range(antal_kolumn):
        cellValue = str(worksheet[get_column_letter(r+1)+str(c+1)].value)
        # change cell to "a-tur"
        if cellValue[0:2] == '07' and  time_in_range(start_a, end_a, datetime.time(int(cellValue[8:10]), int(cellValue[11:13], 0))):
            worksheet[get_column_letter(r+1)+str(c+1)] = 'a-tur'   
        # change cell to "c-tur"
        elif cellValue[8:10] == '21' and  time_in_range(start_c, end_c, datetime.time(int(cellValue[0:2]), int(cellValue[3:5], 0))):
            worksheet[get_column_letter(r+1)+str(c+1)] = 'c-tur'
        # change cell to "natt"
        elif cellValue[0:2] == '21':
            worksheet[get_column_letter(r+1)+str(c+1)] = 'natt'
```